# Automapping and Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I copied example from Fluent NHibernate GitHub documentation for automapping and it doesn't work in my ASP.NET MVC 4 app.

```
public class Product
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Shelf
{
  public virtual int Id { get;  set; }
  public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }

  public Shelf()
  {
    Products = new List<Product>();
  }
}
```

Are models. When I add

```
.Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings
     .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Product>()))
```

to my configuration I get error `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`. Without that, my session works fine and also with mapping defined by me one by one, everything works. Just automapping doesn't work. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in the *Assembly* containing the `Product`, could be some *object/entity*, with such a "missing parameterless constructor" *(some helper object)*. You have to be more specific, try to use the `.Where()` to narrow the set of auto-mapped objects/entities

```
.Mappings(m =>
    m.AutoMappings
     .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Product>()
                 .Where(t => t.Namespace ==...
```

...or something like that. Just be precise what should be auto-mapped.

Comment: It works... Thank you very much. I need to wait to accept answer :)

Comment: Great. Enjoy NHibernate ;)